# Допущена ошибка в синтаксисе

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где допущена ошибка в синтаксисе, все не могу разобраться

```
var str = "bbb /aaa\ bbb /ccc\";
document.write("Ответ: " + str.replace(//.+\\\\/, "!"));
```

Comment: `var str = "bbb /aaa\\ bbb /ccc\\";`

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо, все не могу выучить как правильно записывать дополнительные символы в кавычках...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас две ошибки:

```
"bbb /aaa\ bbb /ccc\"
```

тут вы экранируете последнюю кавычку, и тем самым оставляете строку текста не закрытой. Если кавычка в тексте нужна, то нужно добавить вторую  кавычка `"bbb /aaa\ bbb /ccc\""`, если не нужна, то нужно убрать оператор экранирования "bbb /aaa\ bbb /ccc".

Вторая ошибка:

```
//.+\\\\/
```

Тут нужно экранировать второй слеш, получится `/\/.+\\\\/`